# What is the defining characteristic of a quadratic function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm helping a high school student prepare for an exam, and I'm unsure how to answer this...

Why is $x^3+2x^2$ not quadratic? I thought anything that had a power of 2 was quadratic.

Comment: It's not quadratic becouse it have power that is higher then $2$. Form is quadratic, when the highest power is $2$.

Comment: The power $2$ must occur in the polynomial, and it must be the *highest* power of the variable in the expression.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A quadratic must be a [polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial#Overview) and it must be of *degree* $2$.

[The degree of a polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial#Degree) in $x$ is the *highest power* of $x$ appearing in the function.

So we have that your function is a degree $3$ polynomial, also known as a *cubic*.

Comment: Links and all! :-) +1

Comment: You're so sweet, @Babak. Yes, I am winding down, preparing for bed. You go get 'em! Kill those questions!

Answer (score 4):

It only depends on the highest order term.  In your case, it is a third order polynomial.  If it were just $ax^2+bx+c$ it would be quadratic

Comment: Your first sentence is correct, if it is a polynomial.